# Safari CSS column exhibits overflow bug

Tags: css, safari, multiple-columns

Please check this snippet in Chrome vs Safari:
https://codepen.io/peminator/pen/JjdmQmy)

```css
.col {
  column-count: 5;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.col div {
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}

.col div::before {
  content: '@';
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>A</div>
</div>
```

Why in Safari that @ is not visible? Is there some way to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About how to fix it, it seems that the null transform hack solves the issue

```
.col div::before { 
  ...
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

(I've also tried to play with `z-index` and `overflow` but they have no effect).

It seems a problem related to the `column-count` property anyway

Comment: woow thanks, it works, i tried translateX which did not help and did not think of trying also 3d